# how to check Coldbox route configuration is work?

Tags: coldfusion, routes, coldbox

I'm developing my own blog using Coldbox framework. Also I've added route configuration on my blog. I've created the URL route using addRoute() method given below.

> addRoute(pattern="/login", handler="security.login", action="login");

But that isn't working also the url value goes to

> www.myBlog.dev/login

And I was changed URL directly given below( Security is handler and login is action page)

> www.myBlog.dev/index.cfm/security/login

that was working fine. Anyone give a solution to fix this.

Comment: Are you running it locally with the CF builtin development webserver?

Comment: Yes, I'm running locally using CF11 application server and Apache web server.

Comment: The built-in webserver does not support URL rewrite, but Apache does, did you check if you have enabled `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Okay will do that...

Comment: Thanks for your help that is work great.

Comment: Good to know, will post a little bit more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in Webserver of CF as well some J2EE webservers do not support natively URL rewrite. In this case CF works with the `path` information from the Request Headers and uses the part after `filename.cfm/` - so in your case `security/login` gets resolved, but the route `/login` can not be resolved because the webserver does no route redirect.

Since you are fortunately using Apache locally, you can activate the URL rewrite behavior by turning on `mod_rewrite` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and get the same results as with a production webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Commandbox: has a built-in lucee server that you can start with this command:

```
server start --rewritesEnable
```

and you will have a server up in a less than 10 seconds with url rewriting enabled.

You will found information here: http://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox